# Project in Eclipse working with EclipseLink and having a connection to MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, eclipselink

I'm working with EclipseIndigo, EclipseLink and MySQL I have a table called condition I need to keep it with that name but when I execute this command `"Query qb = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Condition c ")"` in eclipse it throws this exception:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'condition' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor5.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4096)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4028)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2490)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2651)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2683)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2144)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2310)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:931)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:607)
```

I know that MySQL has a command called condition and that's why this command throws me an exception. The question is: there is a form to keep my table named as condition and I can execute this command `"Query qb = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Condition c ")"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reserved words as identifiers must be quoted with MySQL.

Adding following to Condition entity helps (query can remain as it is):

```
@Table(name = "`condition`")
```